# Protractor e2e testing for sorting

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I am writing e2e test cases using protractor. I am trying to write tests for sorting (ascending, descending). This is my html code

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
         <a ng-click="sortBy('Name')" href="" style="text-decoration: none;" class=""> Name</a>
        </td>
        <td>
         <a ng-click="sortBy('RollNo')" href="" style="text-decoration: none;"> Roll Number</a>
        </td>
        <td>
         <a ng-click="sortBy('subject')" href="" style="text-decoration: none;"> Subject</a>
        </td>     
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ANDREW, STRAUSS</td>
        <td>122</td>
        <td>Maths</td>
    </tr>  
    <tr>
        <td>ANDREW, STRAUSS</td>
        <td>123</td>
        <td>Science</td>
    </tr>      
</tbody>
```

Can we test sorting. If yes, how?

Answer (score 10):

To test sorting in any order,

- Click on the sortBy element so that element's get sorted in an order.
- Get the element's text from the columns displayed with a sort order.
- Later store each element's text in an array so that you can check for sorting later.
- Next step is to copy this unsorted array into a temporary array and sort the temporary array.
- Last thing is to check if the element is sorted in the order you need, which you can verify using `expect` statement.

Use Javascript `sort()` method to check sorting in ascending order and `reverse()` to check sorting in descending order.

You can test sorting of elements in ascending order by adding them in an array and then verify it with the sorted array. Here's a sample on how to do it -

```
var sorted = [] , unSorted = [];
var ele = element.all(by.css(tbody tr td:nth-of-type(1)));
ele.each(function(eachName){
    eachName.getText().then(function(name){
        unSorted[i] = name;
        i++;
    });
}).then(function(){
    //check sorting
    sorted = unSorted.slice();
    sorted.sort(); //use sort function of Javascript
    expect(sorted).toEqual(unSorted);
});
```

Similarly you can try with other elements to check for other types of sorting in your case sort by RollNo and subject. If you are facing issues with async errors as protractor is fast, then you can chain your sorting verification code with the loop.

Another method is to use `map()` function of protractor to get all elements text into an array and then check for sorting. I recommend using this. Here's an example -

```
    ele.map(function(eachName){
        return eachName.getText().then(function(unSorted){
            return unSorted;
        });
    }).then(function(unSorted){
            var sorted = unSorted.slice();
            sorted = sorted.sort(); //sort the array
            expect(sorted).toEqual(unSorted); //check if both sorted and unsorted arrays are same
    });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Here I want to test individual column. Like, if I click on student. it should test only student column.

Comment: @N123 I have written the same answer above. Its checking for student column only. Its all about using elements and checking for sorting using arrays. You can test it with other columns too. Let me know if you are unclear of the answer.

Comment: Ya, I am not clear. can you please give me an example. Thanks.

Comment: @N123 updated answer with steps that can be used to test sorting.

Comment: @GirishSortur doing `var sorted = unSorted;` results in a reference copy, not an actual array copy, so the expectation `expect(sorted).toEqual(unSorted);` will always be true. You should use an array copy, using slice() , something like `var sorted = unSorted.slice(0);`

Comment: true @danieln. I forgot to slice the array to copy its value. Updated the answer. Thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to create an array with the sorted text fields and just compare the values in it. After you have sorted the data you could do the following to test an ascending order.

```
const cellElements = element.all(by.css(`table tbody tr td:nth-child(1)`));
const textFields = await cellElements
                .map((el: ElementFinder) => el.getText()
                .then((text: string) => text));

textFields.forEach((description: string, index: number) => {
  if (index > 0) {
    expect(descriptions[index - 1] > description).toBe(true);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
this.Then(/^Verify operations in with priority sorting ascending$/,function(callback){
    var sorted = [] , unSorted = [],i=0;
    var OperationPriority = element.all(by.xpath('//table/tbody/tr//dx-number-box/div/input'));
    console.log("count" +OperationPriority.count);
      OperationPriority.map((eachName) =>{
        unSorted[i] = eachName.getText();
        i++;   
    });
    sorted = unSorted.slice();
    sorted.sort(); 
    console.log(sorted);
    console.log(unSorted);
    expect(sorted).toEqual(unSorted);
callback();
});
```

for **console.log(sorted);
        console.log(unSorted);**
it is printing 2 empty array
and for **expect(sorted).toEqual(unSorted)**
having error "not a function"